# Credentials for call IBM Cloud Function from a node of IBM Watson Assistant?

Tags: websphere, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

How do I set credentials (What parts of credentials I have to set? How it looks like? Where do I get the values?) to call a IBM Cloud Function from IAM-enabled namespace from a node of IBM Watson Assistant?

Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not directly possible as we cannot currently do the specific Token generation for an apikey. Instead it is recommended to use a web_action and secure it via these instructions:
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-actions_web#actions_web_secure

Comment: Do you mean WA action with type = web_action? Can you show me what this action looks like? I've never used it before and don 't know how to set parameters. For type = server WA action looks like this:

"actions": [
    {
      "name": "/IBM1111111_test/test",
      "type": "server",
      "parameters": {
        "param1": "value1",
        "param2": "value1"
      },
      "credentials": "$private.credentials",
      "result_variable": "test_result"
    }
  ]

What does WA action with type = web_action look like?